# matplotlib: how to make proper higher number of subplots with figurecanvastkagg in scrollable window

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a user interface which shows some graphs with scrollbar for my colleagues and I was stuck into last part of the code.

Logic:

Using main window, they are able to add files for run. When they run the code, plots will be shown under the main window in different frame.

Approximately, they use 20-30 files for each run and it shows about 20-30 graph.

I created everything in little bit messy way but it is working. However, when number of subplots is high (>10), plots are look like squeezed on the top of screen and almost bottom part looks empty. I have been trying to figure out for weeks but I couldn't find fine solution even though I saw similar questions as mine and I wanted to ask again.

So how to avoid squahed plots for this situation.

**Note**: I used *resize_callback* in *"FigureCanvasTkAgg"* somehow it solved my problem but I couldn't use *NavigationToolbar2Tk* function properly in my window.

King regards,

Here is my code:

```
def gui():
...
...

def func():
    fig, axs=plt.subplots(nrows=len(files),ncols=1,figsize=(20,10*len(fsa_file)), dpi=100, squeeze=False)
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
    axs=axs.ravel()
    w,h=fig.get_size_inches()



    for v in range(files):

        ...(other things)
        ...
        ...


        axs[v].plot(cb_blue, color="blue")
        axs[v].plot(cb_green, color="green")
        axs[v].plot(cb_black, color="black")
        axs[v].plot(cb_red, color="red")
        axs[v].set_title(files[v].split("/")[6].split(".")[0])


    frame_Agg =Frame(root, width=(20* (fig.dpi)), height=(h * (fig.dpi)))
    canvas=Canvas(frame_Agg,width=(20* (fig.dpi)), height=(h * (fig.dpi)))

    yScrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
    yScrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    figAgg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,canvas)

    figAgg.get_tk_widget().config(width=(20* (fig.dpi)), height=(h (fig.dpi)))
    figAgg.get_tk_widget().config(yscrollcommand=yScrollbar.set)
    figAgg.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=(0,0, 20 * fig.dpi, h * fig.dpi))
    yScrollbar.config(command=figAgg.get_tk_widget().yview)
    figAgg.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP,fill=tkinter.BOTH,expand=1)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(figAgg, frame_Agg)
    toolbar.update()

    figAgg.draw()
    frame_Agg.pack()
    canvas.pack()

return func

def main():
    gui()
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem my self with usage of grid() parameters.